# Do isomorphic ideals yield isomorphic quotient rings?

Tags: abstract-algebra, proof-verification

I am interested in a proof or disproof of the following statement:

> **Conjecture:** If $A$ and $B$ are isomorphic ideals of a ring $R$ then the quotient
>   ring $R/A$ is isomorphic to $R/B$.
>   $$A\cong B\implies R/A\cong R/B$$

I start by assuming the existence of an isomorphism $\phi$ from $A$ to $B$. Then I define the mapping $$\Psi:r+A\mapsto \phi(r)+B.$$

1. $\Psi$ is well-defined.

Suppose $r+A=s+A$ for some $s,r\in R$.

$$ r-s\in A\implies \phi(r)-\phi(s)=\phi(r-s)\in B.$$

Thus $\phi(r)+B=\phi(s)+B$.

2. $\Psi$ is a homomorphism.

   - $$\Psi(r+s+A)=\phi(r+s)+B$$
     $$=\phi(r)+\phi(s)+B=\Psi(r+A)+\Psi(s+A).$$
   - $$\Psi(rs+A)=\phi(rs)+B$$
     $$\phi(r)\phi(s)+B=\Psi(r+A)\Psi(s+A).$$
3. $\Psi$ is one-to-one.

If $\Psi(r+A)=\Psi(s+A)$ then $\phi(r)+B=\phi(s)+B$ which implies $\phi(r-s)\in B$.

How can I get $r-s\in A$?

4. $\Psi$ is onto.

For any $t+B\in R/B$ choose $\phi^{-1}(t)+A\in R/A$. $\quad\square$

---

**Questions: Is this work valid? Do I have sufficient conditions?**

Comment: How does $\phi(r)$ make sense if $\phi: A \to B$?

Comment: Should I extend $\phi$ to be a homomorphism on $R$ and an isomorphism on $A$?

Comment: How you going to do that?

Comment: In what sense do you mean that $\phi$ is a morphism $I \to J$? As a morphism of their sets of elements? Of the additive groups with operation $+$? Viewing them as $R$-modules?  As associative algebras? An isomorphism of the structure I would call "ideal of $R$" could only exist when $I=J$ and would be the identity map.

Comment: Why not try this with the simplest possible commutative ring?

Comment: When two ideals are isomorphic? What's your definition of isomorphic ideals? Surely an ideal does not necessarily have to be a ring, so we can't say they are isomorphic as rings. What is your definition?

Comment: Wait, why aren't ideals rings?

Comment: @M.Nestor  You'll need to declare what you want out of your isos of ideals.  As rings themselves?  $R$-modules?  $\mathbb{Z}$-modules (abelian groups)?

Comment: I can see that this is going to get messy depending on how married people are to rings having a $1$.

Comment: @Randall actually as $R$-modules so they need not be abelian groups. *sigh* and so we return to the rng vs. ring debate.

Comment: @Randall I am not familiar with modules yet, I will look into this, thanks for the comments

Comment: @stressedout  Yes it does:  take $r \in R$ to be an element of $I$.  Then $I$ is closed under its own multiplications.

Comment: @stressedout  It doesn't matter.  If $I$ is a left ideal of $R$ then $xy \in I$ whenever $x, y \in I$.  Precisely because $x \in R$ and $y \in I$ implies $xy \in I$ by definition of left ideal.  So take $x \in I$....

Comment: @Randall Yeah. But it can fail to have an identity element. Right? It pretty much depends on the OP's definition of a ring, whether rings have to be unital and stuff.

Comment: Yeah, of course.  I bet I know exactly what $I$ is if ideals are rings and rings must have $1$.

Comment: It is clear from OP's argument that s/he is assuming that $\phi: A \to B$ is a ring iso.

Answer (score 4):

If isomorphism of ideals means isomorphism as $R$-modules, then here's a very simple counter-example:

Take $R=\mathbb{Z}$. Note that $2\mathbb{Z} \cong \mathbb{Z}$ as $\mathbb{Z}$-modules but $\mathbb{Z}_2 \not\cong 0$.

Here's another counter-example which shows that two ideals can be isomorphic as rings, but their corresponding quotient rings can fail to be isomorphic.

Take $\bar{R}=\bigoplus_{i=1}^{\infty} R$ with component-wise addition and multiplication in $R$ where $R$ is supposed not to be the zero ring.

Now take $I = \bar{R}$ and take $J=\{(0,a_1,a_2,\cdots): a_n\in R\}$ which is obtained by shifting components to the right by one step. Notice that $J$ is indeed an ideal of $\bar{R}$.

Then $I \cong J$ as rings with component-wise addition and multiplication that is induced from $R$. Define $\varphi: I \to J$ given by $(a_1,a_2,\cdots) \mapsto(0,a_1,a_2,\cdots)$. It can easily be verified that
$$\varphi(a_1+a_1',a_2+a_2',\cdots)=\varphi(a_1,a_2,\cdots)+\varphi(a_1',a_2',\cdots)$$
$$\varphi(a_1\cdot a_1',a_2\cdot a_2',\cdots)=\varphi(a_1,a_2,\cdots)\cdot\varphi(a_1',a_2',\cdots)$$

You can see that $\ker{\varphi}=(0,0,\cdots)=\bar{0}$ and you can easily verify that $\psi: J \to I$ given by $(0,a_1,a_2,\cdots) \mapsto (a_1,a_2,\cdots)$ is a right inverse for $\varphi$. Hence, $\varphi$ is surjective too and it's a ring isomorphism.

but $\bar{R} / I = 0$ while $\bar{R}/J \not\cong 0$. Done.

Comment: They are not isomorphic as ideals.

Comment: @Randall Aren't they isomorphic as $\mathbb{Z}$-modules?!

Comment: That's not the question.

Comment: @Randall  when are two ideals isomorphic? I'm asking just for my own learning.

Comment: That's a really good question.  I assumed isomorphic as rings in their own right.  That seems to be what the OP is trying to use in their proof.

Comment: @Randall An ideal of a ring $R$ is a sub-structure of $R$ as an $R$-module. So, if we consider $2\mathbb{Z}$ and $\mathbb{Z}$ as $\mathbb{Z}$-modules, they are isomorphic. At least that was my interpretation of the question. Or am I missing something? (scratches his head)

Comment: There is a definite difference, and both make sense.  It's up to the OP to clarify.

Comment: @Randall I added a new example. How do you like this one? It seems that they're isomorphic as rings this time (unless I'm making a mistake because I have just woken up xD)

Comment: That might be a really good one.

Comment: This smells awful close to the Eilenberg swindle.

Comment: @Randall Yeah. I actually turned it into a proof by adding the missing details by demonstrating an explicit isomorphism of rings between $I$ and $J$. So, you can check it and see whether you agree with me or not. The proof seems fine to me. You can verify it if you wish.

Comment: @Randall Eilenberg–Mazur swindle? (I just looked it up on Wikipedia)  Why? Component-wise addition is well-defined. Don't you agree?

Comment: Not a criticism just a comment.

Comment: I would be really curious if there is a counterexample with $R$ finite. I can't find one.

Comment: @Randall  Actually, I was wondering about the exact same thing. I think that there is no counter-example for finite groups or finite rings but I don't know how to prove it.

Comment: Finite examples exist, but I have only found "lame" ones.  See my new answer.

Comment: @downvoter  what's wrong with this answer?

Answer (score 2):

Why not take $(3)$ and $(10)$ in $\mathbb Z$ which are isomorphic and consider the quotients. One quotient is a PID, the other is not.

Comment: Really, the "PI" part doesn't even matter.  Good example.

Comment: @Randall that is indeed true. I guess the point is that $(3)$ is prime so the quotient is a domain.

Comment: Or that both quotients are finite, but have a different number of elements :P

Comment: @MikePierce what are you doing counting things 'round these parts of town

Comment: I have seen elsewhere that $mZ$ is isomorphic to $nZ$ iff. $m=n$, what is the difference? https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/433049/if-m-and-n-are-distinct-positive-integers-then-m-mathbbz-is-not-ring-is

Comment: @M.Nestor Oh, good point up there^.

Comment: I take ring to preserve identity so that neither of those are rings at all. I took ideal isomorphism to mean isomorphic as $\mathbf Z$-modules (in this case), i.e. abelian groups.

Comment: @M.Nestor: The word "isomorphic" is ***ambiguous***; there are many different kinds of things between which we talk about isomorphisms, and you aren't paying attention to what kind of object we're treating these things as.

Answer (score 1):

Here's another answer, and let me be clear:  I don't think it's all that great.  I think stressed out's answer has the actual good counterexample. I am going to cheat a lot by reducing the problem down to abelian groups, where it is plainly false.  In this answer, I am assuming:

- rings need not have identity, and
- the isomorphism between the ideals was to be a **ring** iso.

The point will be that rings with trivial multiplication make your conjecture false, and there are tons of counterexamples.  If you do not like this and you want a counterexample with a more "honest" ring and not so much cheating, then you have other answers in this thread.  However, this answers a question stressed out and I had on the side about the existence of finite counterexamples.

Given any abelian group $K$, write $K^T$ for the ring with $K$ as the underlying abelian group and multiplication $xy=0$ for all $x, y \in K$ (upper $T$ for "trivial").  The following are easy to prove:

**Claim:**  If $A$ is any subgroup of $K$, then $A^T$ is an ideal of $K^T$.

*Proof:*  Subgroups must contain $0$.

**Claim:**  Every isomorphism $\phi: K \to L$ of abelian groups is also a ring isomorphism $\phi: K^T \to L^T$.

*Proof:*  Well sure, since $\phi(xy)=\phi(0)=0$ and $\phi(x)\phi(y)=0$.

This shows that you can reduce your question down to abelian groups:  if we have an abelian group $K$ with isomorphic subgroups $A$ and $B$, must it be true that $K/A$ and $K/B$ are isomorphic?   If not, then $K^T$ is a ring with ideals $A^T$ and $B^T$ giving a counterexample to your original question.

So, here's an abelian groups counterexample.  Take $K =\mathbb{Z}_2 \times \mathbb{Z}_4$ with subgroups $A= \mathbb{Z}_2 \times \{0\}$ and $B=\{0\} \times \{0,2\}$.  Clearly $A$ and $B$ are subgroups and must be isomorphic since they are each groups of order $2$.  However, $K/A \cong \mathbb{Z}_4$ yet $K/B \cong \mathbb{Z}_2 \times \mathbb{Z}_2$.  As the former is cyclic and the latter is not, the quotients cannot be isomorphic.

Comment: +1. So, it's not true even for finite Abelian groups!

Answer (score 0):

Let $R={\mathbb Z}\times 2{\mathbb Z}$, $I=2{\mathbb Z}\times\{0\}$ and $J=\{0\}\times 2{\mathbb Z}$.  It is obvious that $I\simeq 2{\mathbb Z}\simeq J$.

Define $\varphi:R\to {\mathbb Z}_2\times 2{\mathbb Z}$ by $\varphi((a,2b))=([a]_2,2b)$, then we have
$$
\begin{array}{cl}
     \varphi((a,2b)+(c,2d))&=\varphi((a+c,2(b+d)))=([a+c]_2,2(b+d))  \\
     &=([a]_2+[c]_2,2b+2d)=([a]_2,2b)+([c]_2,2d) \\
     &=\varphi((a,2b))+\varphi((c,2d))
\end{array},
$$
$$
\begin{array}{cl}
     \varphi((a,2b)(c,2d))&=\varphi((ac,4bd))=\varphi((ac,2(2bd)))  \\
     &=([ac]_2,2(2bd))=([a]_2[c]_2,(2b)(2d)) \\
     &=([a]_2,2b)([c]_2,2d)\\
     &=\varphi((a,2b))\varphi((c,2d))
\end{array}.
$$
Thus, $\varphi$ is a ring epimorphism.
Let $(x,2y)\in {\rm Ker}(\varphi)$, then $(0,0)=\varphi(x,2y)=([x]_2,2y)$ and so $x\in 2{\mathbb Z}, y=0$. We can conclude that ${\rm Ker}(\varphi)=2{\mathbb Z}\times\{0\}=I$.
Therefore, $R/I\simeq {\mathbb Z}_2\times 2{\mathbb Z}$.

Define $\psi:R\to {\mathbb Z}$ by $\psi((a,2b))=a$, then we have
$$
\begin{array}{cl}
     \psi((a,2b)+(c,2d))&=\psi((a+c,2(b+d))) \\
     &=a+c \\
     &=\psi((a,2b))+\psi((c,2d))
\end{array},
$$
$$
\begin{array}{cl}
     \psi((a,2b)(c,2d))&=\psi((ac,4bd)) \\
     &=ac \\
     &=\psi((a,2b))\psi((c,2d))
\end{array}.
$$
Thus, $\psi$ is a ring epimorphism.
Let $(x,2y)\in {\rm Ker}(\psi)$, then $0=\psi(x,2y)=x$ and so $x=0$, $2y\in 2{\mathbb Z}$.
We can conclude that ${\rm Ker}(\psi)=\{0\}\times 2{\mathbb Z}=J$.
Therefore, we have $R/J\simeq {\mathbb Z}$.

Hence, $R/I\simeq {\mathbb Z}_2\times 2{\mathbb Z}\not\simeq {\mathbb Z}\simeq R/J$.